# undefined objects

Tags: javascript, html, pubnub

I'm passing an object `"text":"Hey! my chat text here"` into a div tag in DOM I'm using pubnub streaming API. My problem is `undefined` is showing for every object that does not have `"text":"Hey! my chat text here"` when connected to a channel this happens inside `<div id="textbox"></div>`. How do I get rid of `undefined`?

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
Hey, my chat text
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

**javascript code**

```
<script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.15.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8">
    PUBNUB.bind('load', window, function frontpageDemo() {

        var PUBNUB_demo = PUBNUB.init({
            subscribe_key: 'subkey_here',
        });

        PUBNUB_demo.subscribe({
            'channel': "my_channel_here",
            'connect': function(c) {
                console.log('CONNECTED to ' + c);
            },
            'callback': function(m, a, subscribed_channel, c, real_channel) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(subscribed_channel));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(real_channel));
                document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = '<div>' + m.text + '</div>' + document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML;
            }
        })

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I assume I'm not the only one, but the only one to say it, but I read that title completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, title corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I fixed the issue apparently I needed a `if` and `else` statement

```
PUBNUB_demo.subscribe({
            'channel': "my_channel_here",
            'connect': function(c) {
                console.log('CONNECTED to ' + c);
            },
            'callback': function(m, a, subscribed_channel, c, real_channel) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(subscribed_channel));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(real_channel));
                if (m.text === undefined) {}
                else {document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = '<div>' + m.text + '</div>' + document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML;
}
        })
```

More information about [undefined objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) at MDN

Comment: Or `if (m.text !== undefined) { document.getElementById('textbox')... }`